# Finding $x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_4+x_3x_4$ without explicitly finding the roots of $x^4-2x^3-3x^2+4x-1=0$

Tags: solution-verification, contest-math, roots, quadratics, quadratic-forms

> The equation $x^4-2x^3-3x^2+4x-1=0$ has $4$ distinct real roots $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ such that $x_1\lt x_2\lt x_3\lt x_4$ and product of $2$ roots is unity, then find the value of $x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_4+x_3x_4$

This question has an answer on [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3586446/the-equation-x4-2x3-3x24x-1-0-has-four-distinct-real-roots-x-1-x-2-x-3-x) but I am trying to solve it without explicitly finding the roots because the question tells us that the product of $2$ roots is unity. I want to use it.

**My Approach:**

Using Descartes rule, I can see that there is one negative root and three positive roots.

Also, at $x=0, 1, -1$, the value of the polynomial is negative.

Thus, $x_1\lt-1, x_4\gt1$ and $x_2,x_3$ lies between $0$ to $1$.

Thus, I am concluding that $x_2x_4=1$ and $x_1x_3=-1$ (because product of roots is $-1$)

**How to conclusively reject the case $x_3x_4=1$?**

For $\alpha\gt1, \beta\gt1$, $x_1=-\beta, x_2=\frac1\alpha, x_3=\frac1\beta, x_4=\alpha$

Sum of roots$=-\beta+\frac1\alpha+\frac1\beta+\alpha=2\implies\frac1\beta-\beta=2-(\alpha+\frac1\alpha)$

Sum of product of roots taken $3$ at a time$=-\frac1\alpha+\frac1\beta-\alpha-\beta=-4\implies\frac1\beta-\beta=-4+(\alpha+\frac1\alpha)$

Therefore, $\alpha+\frac1\alpha=3, \frac1\beta-\beta=-1$

Multiplying these two, $\frac\alpha\beta-\alpha\beta+\frac1{\alpha\beta}-\frac\beta\alpha=-3$

The question asks us to find $\frac\alpha\beta-\frac\beta\alpha$, that means $-3+\alpha\beta-\frac1{\alpha\beta}$

Can we conclude this approach?

Comment: Vieta's rule should help here

Comment: @Peter that's exactly what I have applied here.

Comment: @Peter Vieta's formula would produce the answer if the desired sum had all six terms of the symmetric polynomial, but this one has only four terms. And it is clear that OP understands this. Please read more carefully.

Comment: You can reject the possibility $x_3x_4=1$ by evaluating the polynomial at $x=1/2$ and $x=2$, but I don't know how much root hunting you want to do :-)

Answer (score 5):

Consider $g(x) = x^4 f(1/x) = -x^{4}+4x^{3}-3x^{2}-2x+1$. Supposing if $x_3 = 1/x_4$ and $x_4 = 1/x_3$, this would mean that $x_3, x_4$ are both roots of this new equation.

Let us verify that there are only two roots of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in common. $f(x) + g(x)$ has no $x^4$ term and no constant term, so it is a cubic polynomial with one root being $x = 0$. This proves our claim.

However, since we already know that $x_2 x_4 = 1$, then $x_2, x_4$ are the roots of $g(x)$. Since $g(x)$ only has these two roots, both $x_3$ and $x_4$ cannot be roots of $g(x)$. Hence $x_3 x_4 \ne 1$.

Comment: Using the reciprocal polynomial is a great idea :-)

Comment: Yep, a trick I learned which suddenly proved useful for this question.

Comment: Another way of using it would be to calculate the gcd of $f$ and $g$, which would lead to the factorization. In a way you started that already by calculating $f+g$!

Comment: There is a small correction: solving $x = 1/x$ we get $x = -1, 1$, and it just remains to show that these are not zeroes of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

I offer to substitute $-3x^2$ as $\left(-4x^2+x^2\right)$, therefore, we will have
$$
x^4-2x^3-3x^2+4x-1=0,
\\
\left(x^4-2x^3+x^2\right)-\left(4x^2-4x+1\right)=0,
\\
x^2\left(x^2-2x+1\right)-\left(2x-1\right)^{2}=0,
\\
x^{2}\left(x-1\right)^{2}-\left(2x-1\right)^{2}=0,
\\
\left(x\left(x-1\right)\right)^{2}-\left(2x-1\right)^{2}=0,
$$
$$
\left(x\left(x-1\right)\right)^{2}-\left(2x-1\right)^{2}=0,\tag{1}
$$
Relatively $(1)$ we must use the very well-known formula
$$
\left(a^2-b^2\right)=\left(a-b\right)\left(a+b\right),\tag{2}
$$
We will receive the next
$$
\begin{cases}
x^2-3x+1=0,\\
x^2+x-1=0.\tag{3}
\end{cases}
$$
Solving $(3)$ you will obtain those $4$ roots and find $x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_4+x_3x_4$.

Comment: Very nice, but the question says "I am trying to solve it without explicitly finding the roots".

Answer (score 0):

For $ \ f(x) \ = \ x^4 - 2x^3 - 3x^2 + 4x-1 \ \ , \ $ the "depressed" polynomial is $ \ f \left(x + \frac12 \right) $ $ \ = \ f(y) \ = \ y^4 - \frac92·y^2 + \frac{1}{16} \ \ , \ $ which, as an even function, has symmetrically-arranged zeroes given by $ \ y^2 \ = \ \frac14·( \ 9 \pm \sqrt{80} \ ) \ \ . \ $  We can approximate the locations as
$$   y^2 \ \ = \ \  \frac14·\left( \ 9 \ \pm \ 9·\sqrt{1 \ - \ \frac{1}{81}} \ \right) \ \ \approx \ \ \frac94·\left( \ 1 \ \pm \ \left[ \ 1 \ - \ \frac{1}{2·81} \ \right] \ \right) \ \ \approx \ \ \frac{1}{8·9} \ \ , \ \ \frac92 \ \ . $$
The four zeroes of $ \ f(x) \ $ are thus estimated by
$$ x_1 \ \approx \ \frac12  -  \frac{3}{\sqrt2} \ < \ 0 \ \ \ , \ \ \ x_2 \ \approx \ \frac12  -  \frac{1}{6\sqrt2}  \ \ \ , \ \ \ x_3 \ \approx \ \frac12  +  \frac{1}{6\sqrt2}  \ \ \ , \ \ \ x_4 \ \approx \ \frac12  +  \frac{3}{\sqrt2} \ > \ 2 \ \ . $$
What is clear from this is that $ \ x_3·x_4 \ $ cannot be equal to  $ \ 1 \ $ and that the only product of two zeroes than *can* be is $ \ \mathbf{x_2}·x_4 \ \ . \ $  [The exact values are in fact $ \ -\phi \ \ , \ \ 2 - \phi \ \ , \ \ \frac{1}{\phi} \ = \ \phi - 1 \ \ , \ \  \phi + 1 \ \ , \ $ but we don't need to know that in order to resolve this particular issue.]

To return to the main question, if we label the four zeroes of $ \ f \left(x + \frac12 \right) \ $  as $ \ -\gamma \  ,  \ -\delta \  ,  \ +\delta \  ,  \ +\gamma \ \ , \ $ then their product is $ \ \gamma^2·\delta^2 \ = \ \frac{1}{16} \ \Rightarrow \ \gamma·\delta \ = \ \frac14 \ \ . \ $  (The estimates above actually happen to fit this nicely.)  We may then express the zeroes of $ \ f(x) \ $ as (using your notation)
$$ x_1 \ \ = \ \ \frac12 \ - \ \gamma \ \ = \ \ -\beta \ \ \ , \ \ \ x_2 \ \ = \ \ \frac12 \ - \ \frac{1}{4 \ \gamma} \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{\alpha}  \ \ \ , $$ $$ x_3 \ \ = \ \ \frac12 \ + \ \frac{1}{4 \ \gamma} \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{\beta}  \ \ \ , \ \ \ x_4 \ \ = \ \ \frac12 \ + \ \gamma \ \ = \ \ \alpha \ \ . $$

We can establish from these results that
$$ \alpha·\frac{1}{\alpha} \ \ = \ \ \left( \ \gamma \ + \ \frac12 \ \right)·\left( \ \frac12 \ - \ \frac{1}{4 \ \gamma} \ \right) \ \ = \ \  \frac{4·\gamma^2 \ - \ 1}{8 \ \gamma} \ \ = \ \ 1 $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ 4·\gamma^2 \ - \ 8·\gamma \ - \ 1 \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \gamma \ \ = \ \ \frac{8 \ + \ \sqrt{64 \ + \ 16}}{8} \ \ = \ \ 1 \ + \ \frac{  \sqrt5}{2} \ \ ,  $$
where we have retained only the positive  solution (we obtain the same result from $ \ \beta·\frac{1}{\beta} \ \ ) $

$$ \Rightarrow  \ \ \alpha \ \ = \ \ \frac{3 +  \sqrt5}{2} \ \ ( \ = \ x_4 \ ) \ \ \ , \ \ \ \beta \ \ = \ \ \frac{1 +  \sqrt5}{2} \ \ ( \ = \ -x_1 \ ) \ \ $$
$$ \Rightarrow  \ \ \alpha·\beta \ \ = \ \ \frac{8 \ + \  4\sqrt5}{4} \ \ = \ \ \ 2 \ + \ \sqrt5 \ \   \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{1}{\alpha·\beta} \ \ = \ \ \frac{  2 \ - \ \sqrt5  }{4 \ - \ 5} \ \ = \ \ \sqrt5 \ - \ 2  $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \alpha·\beta \ - \ \frac{1}{\alpha·\beta} \ \ = \ \ 4 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \  x_1  x_2 \ + \ x_1  x_3 \ + \ x_2  x_4 \ + \ x_3  x_4 \ \ = \ \  -3 \ + \ 4 \ \ = \ \ 1 \ \ . $$

[Using the exact value of the zeroes written above in terms of the Golden Ratio $ \ \phi \ \ , \ $ we verify that
$$ (-2 \phi \ + \ \phi^2) \ + \ (-\phi^2 \ + \ \phi) \ + \ (2 \phi \ - \ \phi^2 \ + \ 2 \ - \ \phi) \ + \ (\phi^2 \ - \ 1) \ \ = \ \ 1 \ \ . \ ] $$

So while we have succeeded in finding the value of the sum of the specified pair-products of zeroes without *explicitly* determining all of the zeroes, it appears to be necessary to characterize those zeroes to a certain extent to evaluate the sum by your approach.